# Multivariable differentiation seems to do nothing?

Tags: calculus

If I have $f(x,t)$ and want to augment this as $f_a(x,t)=f(a^3x,a^5t)$. I want to take $\frac{d}{dt}(f_a(x,t))$.

Do I write $\frac{d}{dt}f(a^3x,a^5t)=f(a^3x,g(t))$ where $g(t) = a^5t$ and sort of chain rule in the right position to obtain:
$$\frac{d}{dt}f_a(x,t) =  \frac{\partial f(a^3x,a^5t)}{\partial t}\cdot a^5,$$
this seem wrong? It feels like I just have $f_t(a^3x,a^5t)=a^5f_t(a^3x,a^5t)$ which is nonsense...

Comment: "Which is nonsense": why ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well if that function is nonzero, then unless $a^5=1$ it is nonsense. I mean I don't see why any of these should be like an exponential

Comment: How do you get that $a^5=1$ ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ does not depend on $t$,

$$\frac{d f(x,t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}.$$

You can "hide" the dependency on $x$ by defining

$$g_x(t):=f(x,t)$$ so that

$$g_x'(t)=\frac{d g_x(t)}{dt}=\frac{d f(x,t)}{dt}=\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}.$$

Now by the chain rule

$$\frac{d g_{a^3x}(a^5t)}{dt}=a^5g_{a^3x}'(a^5t)=a^5\left.\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\right|_{x=a^3x,t=a^5t}.$$